# Is there a way to force a single process to swap most/all of its memory to disk (NON-ROOT)

Tags: linux, swap

We are currently analyzing performance of some of our boxes at work and we find that we have boxes that are swapping a lot and things start crawling when that starts to happen cause we are using spinny disks.

I had a theory that it might actually be faster to start up brand a process and do all the initialization we would normally have to do for that than to wait for  the process to have its memory loaded off of disk.

To test this theory out I want to force a process to swap to disk and I want to see how long it takes to respond after it has been swapped out and compare that to a new process start up, is there a way of forcing a process to swap without modifying swappiness settings or running the box out of memory?

I don't have root on these boxes so basically I need an unprivelaged way of doing/hint to the kernel to do this.

Comment: this sounds odd. You could be configuring your applications to have limits that avoid them arriving at the out of memory/swapped out scenario. To kill off a swapped out process cleanly it needs to be restored which is a bit harder with a brand new process consuming more ram.

Comment: @danblack That does not sound likely. There shouldn't be any need for the kernel to read back pages from swap when you have killed the process. It just need to clean up a few data structures and mark those pages of swap free, which all amounts to a few updates in kernel memory.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is Linux, you might want to set the swappiness variable to its MAX value.  This basically tells the memory management to swap out everything possible that is not currently in use. This value guides how much (and how often) your Linux kernel will copy RAM contents to swap

To permanently set:

1. Edit `/etc/sysconfig.conf`
2. Add the following line to the file
   `vm.swappiness=100`
3. Reboot

Or to temporarily set till the next reboot:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=100
```

This will allow you to test your assumptions on your mix of jobs.

Comment: This is linux but I already said that I don't have root so this wont work

Comment: Hmmm...the assumption is that posters in this group are administrators w/ `root` access.

Comment: Tried `sysctl vm.swappiness=100; cat file > /dev/null`, but does not help. File is still written to "available" RAM instead of the swap file.

Comment: @mgutt that's cache, not process memory, those are completely different and separate pools of memory. Kernel never swaps out file system cache, it just drops it.

Answer (score 1):

Collect response time data of your actual applications, whatever you do. Log user response time, process start times, and whatever other performance metric is important to you.

On Linux, cgroups can have a memory limit beyond which processes in that group page out. A systemd service can set such a limit with the `MemoryLimit` directive, see the man page or [RHEL's resource management guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/resource_management_guide/index#sec-Modifying_Unit_Files). Remember that systemd units can be per user, root privilege not required.

Do not spend a lot of time trying to mock up a low memory condition, it is unlikely to perform like production's workload. If you can change the application to lazy starting or loading processes, do that in test then production. And measure the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* actually do this on newer kernels but you will still need root.

There is a special syscall `process_madvise` you can use that that lets you select mappings of memory from a foreign process and you can pass the `MADVISE_PAGEOUT` flat to fault out the memory into swap.

From `madvise(2)`

> ```
> MADV_PAGEOUT (since Linux 5.4)
>        Reclaim  a given range of pages.  
>        This is done to free up memory occupied by these pages. 
>        If a page is anonymous, it will be swapped out.  
>        If a page is file-backed and dirty, it will be written
>        back to the backing storage.  The advice might be ignored for 
>        some pages in the range when it is not applicable.
> ```

The idea tickled me so I wrote a program to try it out.
You can compile it with `gcc -o swapout swapout.c`. You pass it a pid:

```
$ sudo ./swapout 1217683
Swapping out 3075.215 MiB of process memory
Swapped out 2479.293 MiB of process memory
```

My testing of it suggested the kernel doesn't always respect your wishes, however my manual checking of a heavy pid that used a lot of memory indicates that the kernel did at least swap out *some* of the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/pidfd.h>

ssize_t process_madvise(
        int fd,
        const struct iovec *vec,
        size_t vlen,
        int advice,
        int flags)
{
    return syscall(SYS_process_madvise, fd, vec, vlen, advice, flags);
}

/* Retrieve a list of all anonymous mappings that this process
 * is using */
size_t get_anonymous_mappings(
        pid_t pid,
        struct iovec **vecs,
        int *nvecs)
{
    char buf[1024] = {0};
    FILE *maps = NULL;
    struct iovec *v = NULL;
    size_t total = 0;
    int nv = 0;

    v = alloca(32768 * sizeof(struct iovec));

    /* Open the map file for pid */
    snprintf(buf, 1023, "/proc/%lu/maps", pid);
    maps = fopen(buf, "re");
    if (!maps) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot access process maps: %m\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    while (1) {
        char buf[1024] = {0};
        char path[256] = {0};
        char perm[32] = {0};
        uint64_t off, inode;
        uint8_t *e, *b, dev_min, dev_maj;
        int rc;

        if (!fgets(buf, 1023, maps))
            break;

        memset(path, 0, 256);
        memset(perm, 0, 32);
        rc = sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx %s %llx %hhx:%hhx %llu %s", 
                &b, &e, perm, &off, &dev_maj, &dev_min, &inode, path);
        if (rc < 6) 
            continue;

        /* Must all be 0 to be an anonymous mapping */
        if ((off || dev_min || dev_maj || inode)) 
            continue;

        if (strcmp(path, "[heap]") != 0 && strcmp(path, "[stack]") != 0 && path[0] != 0)
            continue;

        total += (e-b);
        v[nv].iov_base = b;
        v[nv].iov_len = (size_t)(e-b);
        nv++;
    }

    if (ferror(maps)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file: %m\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    *nvecs = nv;
    *vecs = calloc(nv, sizeof(struct iovec));
    if (!(*vecs)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate vectors: %m\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    memcpy((*vecs), v, nv * sizeof(struct iovec));

    fclose(maps);
    return total;

fail:
    if (maps)
        fclose(maps);
    if (*vecs)
        free(*vecs);
    return -1;
}

int main(
        int argc,
        char **argv)
{
    int n, rc;
    int pfd = -1;
    struct iovec *vecs = NULL;
    int nvecs = -1;
    size_t mapsz;
    pid_t pid = -1;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Give process ID of process to swap out.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (pid <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Pid is not a valid process ID.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pfd = pidfd_open(pid, 0);
    if (pfd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot access process: %m\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    mapsz = get_anonymous_mappings(pid, &vecs, &nvecs);
    if (mapsz < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    printf("Swapping out %.3f MiB of process memory\n", (double)mapsz / 1048576.0);

    /* Only 1024 vectors can be processed at once */
    n=0;
    mapsz = 0;
    while (n < nvecs) {
        int l;
        if (nvecs-n > 1024)
            l = 1024;
        else
            l = nvecs-n;

        rc = process_madvise(pfd, &vecs[n], l, MADV_PAGEOUT, 0);
        if (rc < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot swap out process: %m\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        n += l;
        mapsz += rc;
    }

    printf("Swapped out %.3f MiB of process memory\n", (double)mapsz / 1048576.0);
    free(vecs);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```